# Debugging a function with table type as input parameter

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Can anybody let me know how can i debug a functions with table type as input parameter and this function returns a table type pipelined.

Please see below details.When i try to test the function it creates below anonymous block but when i click on debug button it gives error:

Anonymous block:

```
declare
  -- Non-scalar parameters require additional processing 
  result t_bmk_q;
  pit_srch_str t_parm;
begin
  -- Call the function
  result := f_bmk_srch(pit_srch_str => pit_srch_str,
                               piv_op => 'ALL');
end;


---f_bmk_q  function returns table type t_bmk_q   pipelined


defintions:
==============
t_bmk_q  --->table type

t_bmk_q is TABLE OF r_bmk_q -->object of some attributes.


pit_srch_str ---> is parameter of type  t_parm which is table type  of r_parm


--plz see def of r_parm:

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE r_parm AS OBJECT
    (
        p_abc                 varchar2(200)
                ,p_new_val               varchar2(2000)
                ,CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION r_parm
                  (
                   p_abc                 varchar2
                   ,p_new_val                varchar2
                  ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
        );

Example:I have below sample values to test and debug:
r_parm('TAB1.VALUE','123321123')
```

Thanks
Rajesh

Comment: And... what error did you get? And did you notice the 'require additional processing' part?

Comment: Yes i noticed but i am not sure what additional things i need to add for multi dimensional table type object input parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using a PL/SQL Developer Test Window to run the tests.  I recognise the comment `Non-scalar parameters require additional processing`.

PL/SQL Developer's Test Window doesn't handle pipelined functions too well.
You are best off removing the `result` variable and wrapping the function call in `open :cursor for select * from table(...)`.  Add a variable named `cursor` of type Cursor to the variables list below the window.

To populate the input table, you can simply 'call' the table type, passing each row in the table as a separate argument.  For example,

```
t_parm(r_parm(...), r_parm(...), r_parm(...))
```

You can add as many rows to the table as you like this way.

Putting both of these changes together, we have something like the following:

```
declare
  pit_srch_str t_parm;
begin
  -- Create input table.    
  pit_srch_str := t_parm(
            r_parm('TAB1.VALUE','123321123'),
            r_parm('TAB2.VALUE','456597646')
  );

  -- Call the function
  open :cursor for select * from table(f_bmk_srch(pit_srch_str => pit_srch_str,
                               piv_op => 'ALL'));
end;
/
```

Once you've run the function, you can get the results from the `cursor` variable (use the `...` button at the far right).